# How to render a different controller in zend view?

Tags: php, zend-framework

How to render a different controller in zend view. Before that I was using iframe. In iframe it is working fine

```
<iframe src="/<?php echo FRONT_ROOT_PATH;?>/<?php echo ADMIN_ROOT_PATH;?>/contentarea?formid=<?php echo $this->parent1[0];?>" width="99%" frameborder="0"  height="800" scrolling="yes" name="content" ></iframe>
```

Now I am using

```
<?php echo $this->partial('contentarea/index.phtml', array(
    'form_id' =>$this->parent1[0] )); ?>
```

or

```
<iframe src="/<?php echo FRONT_ROOT_PATH;?>/<?php echo ADMIN_ROOT_PATH;?>/leftmenu" width="100%" frameborder="0"  height="800" style="border:1px solid #e0e0e0;" name="left-area" ></iframe>
```

now i am using this as

```
<?php echo $this->render('leftmenu/index.phtml'); ?>
```

In leftmenu/index.phtml i have

```
<?php echo $this->listingdetails; ?>
```

without iframe its not working. Please help me